# Qiskit code works even without measure_all() with qasm_simulator

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am need help in understanding about the `measure_all()` of the qiskit.
The below code is correct even though `measure_all()` is not being used.

```
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit import execute
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit


circ = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.cx(0,2)

backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")


job = execute(circ, backend, shots = 100000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circ)
print(counts)
```

It would be great if someone can explain about the `measure_all()` concept, where to use it and where not to use it?

Comment: I tried your code on my machine. It gave me the error message: "No counts for experiment ..."

Comment: Thank you @Egretta.Thula for the response. I tested the code on `qiksit version 0.32.1`, `python version 3.8.18`. It gives me result `{'000': 100000}`

Comment: I ran my test on version 0.46.0

Comment: Really not sure why things changes so much even for such a basic code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are noticing that measurement behavior is different in different versions of Qiskit. In `qiskit==0.33.1`, we have the following behavior:

```python
import qiskit
print(qiskit.__qiskit_version__)
```

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.19.1', 'qiskit-aer': '0.9.1', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.7.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.18.2', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.9.5', 'qiskit': '0.33.1', 'qiskit-nature': None, 'qiskit-finance': None, 'qiskit-optimization': None, 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}
```

```
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit import execute
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit


circ = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.cx(0,2)

backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")


job = execute(circ, backend, shots = 100000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circ)
print(counts)
```

```
{'000': 100000}
```

But in the next update `qiskit==0.34.0` there is an error:

```python
import qiskit
print(qiskit.__qiskit_version__)
```

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.19.1', 'qiskit-aer': '0.10.1', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.7.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.18.3', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.9.5', 'qiskit': '0.34.0', 'qiskit-nature': None, 'qiskit-finance': None, 'qiskit-optimization': None, 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}
```

```
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit import execute
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit


circ = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.cx(0,2)

backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")


job = execute(circ, backend, shots = 100000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circ)
print(counts)
```

```
QiskitError: 'No counts for experiment "<qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit.QuantumCircuit object at 0x1550e7790>"'
```

So your issue is not with the `measure_all()` concept per say, but rather you just need to keep notes of the versions in which these changes take place.

**Clarification:** It should also be noted that in the `qiskit==0.33.1` case, the output `{'000': 100000}` is reflecting the fact that no measurements have been loaded in to the classical bits (so the values all remain zero). If a measurement statement is included, then this circuit will have GHZ state measurement statistics:

```python
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit import execute
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit


circ = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.cx(0,2)
circ.measure(range(3), range(3)) # actually measure the circuit

backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")


job = execute(circ, backend, shots = 100000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circ)
print(counts)
```

```
{'000': 50094, '111': 49906}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick Mertes for this great help.